# Recuperar EditText de Fragments na Activity

Tags: android

Tenho uma Activity com Actionbar e três Tabs, em cada Tab é carregado um Fragment diferente e em cada fragment desse tenho um formulário.
Ao terminar de preencher os tres formulários, quando tocar no botão salvar quero poder recuperar as informações de cada fragment e persistir no SQLite.

Minha dúvida é saber como faço pra acessar os campos de cada fragment.

Já tentei fazer usando

```
Fragment1 detalhes = (Fragment1) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("frag1");
```

mas só funciona pra recuperar o campo no fragment atual.
Como faço pra recuperar de todos?

Comment: Para puder ajudá-lo necessito de ver o código, na sua actividade, onde é feita a gerência e criação das `Tab's`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você passa de um fragment para o outro você vai ter que mandar os dados que foram preenchidos para o outro para não perder.

Por exemplo, crie uma classe com todos os campos do formulários representados como atributos. Na hora de trocar do fragment A para o B, você pega todos os dados que foram informados na tela e joga para a classe que criou. No fragment B você vai receber esses dados e vai acrescentar mais os dados que foram informados agora.

Dessa forma você pode ir pra frente ou pra trás na troca de tela e vai sempre manter os dados. Ao chegar no último fragment, quando clicar em Salvar, basta pegar os dados da classe de transporte e persistir eles.

Comment: Deu certo aqui!
Fiz como indicado e funcionou perfeito.
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Agora meu surgiu outra duvida.  
Eu estou usando o método onPause() do Fragment pra pegar os dados informados na tela e preencher essa classe de transporte.  
Meu problema é quando estou no ultimo Fragment. Pois eu uso um botão no ActionBar para salvar e o método esta na Activity, só que como é o ultimo Fragment, o método onPause() dele não foi chamado, e assim, esses dados ainda não foram passados para essa classe de transporte.  
Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução simples pra manter os dados entre as transições do fragment, é a partir do método `setOffscreenPageLimit()`. Onde é passado a quantidade de telas como parâmetro, no exemplo abaixo os dados serão mantidos entre 3 telas.

Importante frisar o maior consumo de memória.

```
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```